# java.io.EOFException with paho

Tags: java, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

i want to make stress test on mosquitto, so i create some code as below

```
for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++) {
        final int j = i;
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(j + " : ************");
                try {
                    MqttClient client = new MqttClient("tcp://192.168.88.203", SERVER_CLIENTID_PREFIX + j); 
                    client.connect();

                    MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage((j + ":me").getBytes());
                    message.setQos(2);

                    client.publish(TOPIC_PREFIX + j, message);
                } catch (MqttSecurityException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MqttException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
```

But, I got some errors like `EOFException` during run and some client is disconnect. 
I want to know how many clients can publish messages at same time with one mosquitto server, and how can I make the stress test. Thanks!

The detail exception is :

```
    Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:162)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.wire.MqttInputStream.readMqttWireMessage(MqttInputStream.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:121)
    ... 1 more
```

And I found some log from mosquitto server:

```
1383736170: Socket read error on client Server-82, disconnecting.
```

Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Can you post the exact exception? Sounds like the socket was closed. Can you try with a higher MQTT keepAlive value? I suspect that under this high load the Paho client doesn't manage to send pings properly.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have append detail exception. What about the "keepAlive" value which you mention. i can not found it in mosquitto.conf , i only found "keepalive_interval" , is it right? thanks again

Comment: 32109 is the error code for "Connection Lost" on the client side. That means the socket was closed unexpectedly. 

If you want a higher keepAlive, you have to pass a MqttConnectOptions object to your connect() method with the defined keepAlive.

If that doesn't help, I suspect that perhaps you are reaching a limit on the server side. Did you try with other brokers like HiveMQ or RabbitMQ?

Comment: Thank you , i modify my code as :client = new MqttClient("tcp://192.168.88.203", "Server-" + j); 
      MqttConnectOptions connOpt = new MqttConnectOptions();
      connOpt.setConnectionTimeout(60 * 10);
      connOpt.setKeepAliveInterval(60 * 5);

Comment: but ,it can not make a good effection. I found if i don't publish message, the mosquitto server could accept 800 client connetion, but when i publish message, the '32109' error will be shown. I have no idea about this, sigh....

Comment: hi, when i run this run on linux os, it can work well, so pleasure, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 12):

I got this exact same error using code similar to above. I found that changing the QOS to 0 fixed the problem.

```
message.setQos(0);
```

[Edit] A bit more digging and I discovered that the MQTT plugin for RabbitMQ doesn't support a QOS of 2. http://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html

Answer (score 3):

My issue resulted from the clientId being the same for the publisher/subscriber. Was getting errors with Persistence datastore already being in use as well.

Comment: Thanks solved my problem. Was using same clientID for both pub and sub. Changing IDs worked.

Comment: So I am not allowed to publish and subscribe with one single mqtt client?

Answer (score 2):

client id is the problem, generating a random test

```
MqttClient.generateClientId ();
```

Comment: In my case after adding MqttClient.generateClientId(),Frequency of occurring this issue  got reduced. If I set keepalive as 20 seconds,im not at all getting EOF exception. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was because I was accidentally using a `tcp://...` URL instead of `ssl://...` and the server was configured not to allow insecure connections.

I also had to do as @Aidan said and reduce the QoS from 2 to 1.

**Edit**: I'm not 100% sure, but I think the server I'm using is RabbitMQ, and that assigns a [non-standard meaning to the QoS values](https://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html). It's probably a more sensible meaning to be honest:

> Transient (QoS0) subscription use non-durable, auto-delete queues that
>   will be deleted when the client disconnects.
>
> Durable (QoS1) subscriptions use durable queues. Whether the queues
>   are auto-deleted is controlled by the client's clean session flag.
>   Clients with clean sessions use auto-deleted queues, others use
>   non-auto-deleted ones.

Answer (score 0):

There's a 1024 files/sockets limit in linux but you can upset it,`ulimit -n 4096` see:
[mqtt mosquitto linux connection limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087396/mqtt-mosquitto-linux-connection-limit)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happen when you will try to send large data set. Try to decrease dataset size. It solved problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is add MqttClient.generateClientId

```
MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence()
MqttClient client = new MqttClient("tcp://192.168.88.203",MqttClient.generateClientId(),persistence); 
client.connect();
```

or

```
MqttClient client = new MqttClient("tcp://192.168.88.203", MqttClient.generateClientId+SERVER_CLIENTID_PREFIX)
```

The identifier must be random.
I had this problem in scala and that was my solution.

Comment: Thanks for the info,how this problem will be resolved by adding generateClientId()